# Why did they choose those specific victims in the second round of the Triwizard Tournament?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, triwizard-tournament

The victims in the Second Task for the Triwizard Cup were Harry's friends, the girl he likes, a little girl that Harry wants to protect. Myrtle prompts Harry in which direction to swim. This leads to the fact that Harry is *the first* who arrive to the victims. And he *waits* until all the guys are saved. Why was this provocation created?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you asking what the criteria was for choosing the victims?

Comment: Why they chose specifically these people?

Comment: Harry only stayed because he misunderstood the task, and thought the captives would literally die. Regardless of who the captives were, it was the misunderstanding, not the people, that ultimately kept him there.

Answer (score 7):

In the second task, each champion has one hour to rescue a person they love.

- **Ron Weasley** is Harry's *best friend*. (along with Hermione who's already Krum's hostage)
- **Hermione Granger** is Victor Krum's *love interest*. (They went to the Yule ball together.)
- **Cho Chang** is Cedric Diggory's *girlfriend*.
- **Gabrielle Delacour** is Fleur Delacour's *little sister*.

Harry stays with the others because he believes they could die if their champion doesn't claim them. This is incorrect (Dumbledore wouldn't let that happen) but Harry has a "saving people thing".

Comment: You don't deny that 3/4 people are important to Harry? And it's a bit confusing him. After all, if you look from any other champion, the task of each has only 1 correct answer.

Comment: Two of the people were bound to be ones Harry knew, since one was chosen on purpose, and the other would be someone important to another Hogwarts student. Hermione's just coincidence.

Comment: @Adamant 2, obviously so.

Answer (score 3):

## Each one was chosen to be important to a specific champion.

The only one who was actually chosen specifically to be important to Harry was Ron Weasley, his best friend. Hermione and Cho also happened to be important to Harry, but that had nothing to do with why they were chosen for the task. Hermione was chosen for Viktor Krum, since she was sort of going out with him, and Cho was chosen for Cedric since she was his girlfriend. Gabrielle, Fleur’s sister, had no particular importance to Harry - but it didn’t matter, since the point was for her to be important to *Fleur*.

## Harry rescued them all because he (illogically) thought they’d die.

Harry’s decision to save all the people tied underwater wasn’t based on how important they were to him, it was because he thought their lives were in danger.

> “Harry looked around, waiting. Where were Fleur and Krum? Time was getting short and, according to the song, the hostages would be lost after an hour …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 26 (The Second Task)*</sup></sub>

He *may* have been somewhat more motivated thinking Hermione and Cho were in danger, but he generally has a hero complex and tendency to be “noble” rather than think things out logically. He did start trying to free Hermione first, before either Cho or Gabriellle, so he was probably going in order of importance to him (whether consciously or not) but he wouldn’t have needed them to be important to him for him to want to save them.

> “You take your own hostage,’ one of them said to him. ‘Leave the others …”
>
> “No way!’ said Harry furiously – but only two large bubbles came out.
>
> ‘Your task is to retrieve your own friend … leave the others …’
>
> ‘*She’s* my friend, too!’ Harry yelled, gesturing towards Hermione, an enormous silver bubble emerging soundlessly from his lips. ‘And I don’t want *them* to die, either!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 26 (The Second Task)*</sup></sub>

After both Hermione and Cho are saved, Harry insisted on saving Fleur’s sister, who he’d never even met before, much less felt close to.

Comment: Do you think that this wasn't a provocation?

Comment: @ElectricKate What do you mean by “provocation”? If you mean he’d be more interested in saving his friends, then yes, though he wouldn’t let *anyone* die, because he isn’t the type to do that.

Comment: if, @ElectricKate, you are asking if all the participants were specifically targeted at Harry for evil purposes, then, no. Moody / Crouch had no interest in sabotaging Potter, rather, he wanted him to win to ensure his entry and success in the maze.

Comment: @NKCampbell, Moody/Crouch didn't choose victims.

Comment: But how do they select between **multiple** options for each champion? Like if Hermione *wasn't* Krum's love interest and it came down between her and Ron for Harry to save? Would it be random at that point? That's how I'm interpreting what the OP is asking between the question title and the question text.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd, does it bother you when Myrtle prompts Harry where to go?

Comment: @ElectricKate Um...should it?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd, In my opinion this is the root cause of this situation.

Comment: I didn't suggest Moody did @ElectricKate, my comment was to demonstrate that Moody had no motive to do so nor to bait Harry into failing that task. Additionally, Myrtle only tells Harry what Cedric had already figured out.

Comment: @NKCampbell, I mean another episode: "You want to try over there!" she said, pointing. "I won't come with you....I don't like them much, they always chase me when I get too close...."